# How to select all entries of a MySQL table except the last one?

Tags: mysql

How to select all entries but the last one in MySQL?
I tried the following statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM table name
ORDER BY id
SELECT id FROM lot_master WHERE `id auto increment` ORDER BY id decs LIMIT 1
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: SELECT * from <table name> where id <> (select max(id) from <table name>)

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name from shopping_cart where id<>(select max(id) from shopping_cart);
```